# Converting from int to binary string to int using 2's complement

Tags: c, binary, int, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

There is a binary string `10001110` which I know is using 2's complement. I know it will be 8 bits.

It is given to me in the form of an `unsigned int` which equals 142.

I then need to convert this back to `10001110`

then invert all the bits and add one resulting in it equaling `01110010`

and then convert this to a `signed int` equaling -114.

How can I do this? I'm relatively new to C and have spent ages trying to figure it out!

Essentially I want to write a function that takes the `unsigned int` 142 and returns the `signed int` -114

Comment: And it'll always have 8 bits?  Or what?

Comment: Yes in this case I know it's 8 bits. I would like to be able to pass this as a parameter to the function though.

Comment: Isn't 01110010 just 114 (not -114)?

Comment: 1) convert to `unsigned char`, 2) use bitwise "not", 3) convert to `int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB you forgot "add one" ;-)

Comment: yes 01110010 is 114 but the actual number that was stored is -114 because it was 2's compliment

Comment: That's not clear: 142 is actually -114. If you invert the bits and add one you get 114. So the function would take 142 and return 114, not -114. If this is wrong then you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: @TomJenkinson: FYI: it's two's *complement*, not compliment (no 2 ever complimented me on anything :( ).

Comment: Just so you know, if `value` is definitely 8 bits in size, and unsigned, then `int x = (((int)value + 128) & 0xff) - 128;` .  There are faster ways as well, i imagine...like subtracting 256 if value >= 128.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the solution I finally came up with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getBit(int no, int bit) // get bit at certain position
{
    bit--;
    return (no & (1 << bit)) >> bit;
}

void complementNBits(int *no, int count) // invert certain number of bits
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<count; i++)
    {
        *no ^= 1 << i;
    };
}

int main() 
{
    unsigned int unsignedNo=142;

    int negative = 0;   
    signed int signedNo=0;

    // check if MSB is set to determine if negative

    if (getBit(unsignedNo, 8)) // if MSB is set
    {
        negative = 1;
        // invert these 8 bits and add 1. the rest of the MSBs will already be 0
        complementNBits(&unsignedNo, 8);
        unsignedNo++;
    }

    signedNo = unsignedNo;
    if (negative)
    {
        signedNo = signedNo * -1;
    }

    printf("THE SIGNED INTEGER: %i\n", signedNo);

}
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Uh ... WHY?!?  Please take another look at my responses.  Why on Earth can't you just "cast" the value?  What part of "an integer is an integer ... the *bits* are always *the same*" don't you get???

Comment: It doesn't work because the MSB (sign) bit would be in the wrong place as an int doesn't equal 8 bits.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you're confused.  an 8-bit "-142" has the same lower 8 bits, and the same "1" MSB, as a 32-bit "-142".  Or a 16-bit, or 64-bit "-142".  The only difference is one is narrower than the rest, and has fewer "1" bits to the left.  You do *NOT* need to do any tortured bit-bit-bit manipulation to get the value you're looking for.  Try it :)

Comment: If I do `printf("%i\n", (signed int) unsignedInt);` it gives me the wrong no :/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the bit pattern.  You just need to sign-extend to match the bit-length of the signed int result.  Easiest way to do this is to check the sign bit of the input and then or with -1 sifted left by the bit length if it's set.

```
int toSignedInt(unsigned int value, int bitLength)
{
    int signedValue = value;
    if (value >> (bitLength - 1))
        signedValue |= -1 << bitLength;
    return signedValue;
}
```

**Explanation**

In 8-bit two's complelement the bit pattern for an unsigned 142 and a signed -114 are identical.  So if your integer type is 8 bits you just have to convert the type.  However, if you've got, say, 32-bit integers, but you want to treat them as if they're 8-bit two's complement, then you need to set the left-hand 24 bits to 1 if the sign bit is 1.

Comment: `128 & -1 == 128`, if we assume two's complement.  If we don't, then $DEITY knows what you'll get.

Comment: I always thought that `x &= -1` doesn't change `x` at all. Maybe you meant 'x ^= -1`?

Comment: Doh.  My mistake should be `value | (-1 << bitLength)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm starting to understand it now! Does this rely on the computer using 2's complement (as oppose to something else like sign and magnitude)? Also is `int` the same as `signed int`?

Comment: Yes, this relies on the compiler using two's complement.  And yes, `int` is usually the same as `signed int`.

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to do this without having to rely on this fact. I don't care how the final `signed int` containing the number is actually stored in memory (probably 2's complement). I just need to be certain that the binary string of the `unsigned int` I am given is treated as a string that that has been encoded, if that is the right word, with 2's complement.

Comment: I think it's true to say that almost any language or system that you're likely to want to use will represent the integers using two's complement.  C certainly does, so I don't think that's a real concern.

Comment: And in your question you say that you know the bit pattern of the input value is two's complement, but that you're given that value as an integer, not a string of bits.  This implies that the system you're using is two's complement.

Answer (score 2):

Think about about what you can do with bitwise operators. You can test whether a bit is 1 or 0 like this:

```
int bit = value & 1;
```

You can also shift the bits in an int like this:

```
val = val >> 1;
```

To test the i'th bit in an int you can do this:

```
int bit = (value >> i) & 1;
```

So using this information, you could convert the given integer into binary and store that in a char array(it will be in reversed order already if you count up!) then manipulate the char to your preference. Hopefully this is a big enough hint to get you on your feet and started.

Comment: That's sounds like a lot of work, when the operator `~` can invert all the bits in one go.

Comment: The ~ will invert all the bits though and only the first 8 bits are actually used so only those 8 should be inverted. All the other bits will already be set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just subtract 256 from whatever value you are given?

Comment: `int func(unsigned int value) { return (unsigned char)(-value); }` would also do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Dude - why did you close your original question????

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713020/2s-complement-conversion-in-c/13713071#comment18835229_13713071

My response is the same as the first:

- An integer is an integer.  Whether it's "signed" or "unsigned"; whether it's "ones complement" or "twos complement" - the bits are always the same.
- If you want to "convert" a signed value into an unsigned value, a C cast is usually the best, simplest, most efficient and clearest approach (code example below).
- The vast majority of CPU architectures are twos complement
- If, for whatever reason, you want to check if your CPU architecture is ones complement, then just test for `-0 == +0`.  Twos complement doesn't *have* a "negative zero" (just zero).  Ones complement does.

PS:

> Q: Essentially I want to write a function that takes the unsigned int
>   142 and returns the signed int -114

A:

```
int silly_convert (int i)
{
  return (signed char)i;
}
```

This is exactly the same as I suggested in my response to your original post.

Comment: I close the question because I didn't explain it very well.